# Send multiple checkbox value through to an INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to send through multiple value through to an INSERT string but the value returns as NULL.

I am trying to send two values to a single table, a member Id and a team Id, the team id is the checkbox value where the as the member ID in this example stays the same so my table collects the integers like so:

```
teamMember (table name)
id, memberId, teamId
1,  1,        2
2,  1,        1
3,  2,        3
```

I hope you get the idea.

This is my my insert:

```
$memberId = $_POST['memberId'];
$teamId = $_POST['teamId'];

foreach($teamId as $val){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO teamMember (teamId, memberId) VALUES ('$val','$memberId')";
}


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
}
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form action="cmt.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="memberId" value="<?php echo $memberId; ?>">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM team WHERE dashboardId = $dashboardId";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo '<input name="teamId[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $row["id"] . '">' . $row["name"] . '<br><br>';
                    }
                }
            ?> 
<form>
```

I just need to checkbox values to come through as an array so I can add multiple team ids along with the user ID i am selecting the team for.

The question is how do I insert multiple rows as this only seems to be inserting a single row each time.

Comment: you should use `foreach` to your array and do an insert inside it, that's how I did it on my project before.

Comment: FWIW, unless the list of teams is vast, I'd just load them all into json and handle the filtering in a bit of JavaScript

Comment: Hmm, I just tried that but im still only getting a single result inserted

Comment: @Roljhon could you show me an example?

Comment: @Strawberry do you have an example I could see? The team list isn't going to to be very big at all, I mean maybe like 10 at most ever really

Comment: what is `dashboardId`??

Comment: @B.Desai all the teams and members belong to a dashboard which is what the this form is a process of, so I am creating teams and member for a 'dashboard'

Comment: Roljhon, is half right, but the INSERT shouldn't normally occur inside the loop - with one important caveat (just beyond the scope of the present discussion)

Comment: Actually forget my first comment- it applies to a select rather than an insert- need coffee

Comment: @PhpDude check my update answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example like this:

```
$teamId = $_POST['teamId'];
$memberId = $_POST['memberId'];

foreach($teamId as $val){

  //I am confused with the $dashboardId, i supposed its $teamId?
  $sql = "INSERT INTO teamMember (teamId, memberId) VALUES ('".$val."','".$memberId."')";

 //execute the query here
}
```

**OR**

```
$teamId = $_POST['teamId'];
$memberId = $_POST['memberId'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO teamMember (teamId, memberId)"
$c = 0;
foreach($teamId as $val){

  if($c == 0){
      $sql.=" VALUES ('".$val."','".$memberId."')";
  }else{
      $sql.=", ('".$val."', '".$memberId."')";
  }

  $c++;
}

//execute query here
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
}
```

`$val` is the value for each checkbox

Comment: Build the list of values inside the loop but execute the query outside the loop

Comment: @Strawberry he is trying to insert multiple rows, I think this is what it should like

Comment: No. You're executing n queries. You only need to execute 1.

Comment: DARE TO EXPLAIN THE DOWNVOTE??

Comment: Either way, if I perform the insert inside the foreach it returns as null, if I insert outside of the loop there values arnt being passes form the teamId as val

Comment: @PhpDude update your post of you have done so far. This will actually going to work, and you can also follow Strawberry's suggestion.

Comment: @Strawberry yes, I'm just showing how he could extract the values from the array of elements and do the insert. Either way, both would work though but maybe my answer will not be the best.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing wrong variable

```
$memberId = $_POST['memberId'];
$teamId = implode(',', $_POST['teamId']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO teamMember (teamId, memberId) VALUES ('$teamId', '$memberId')"; //<----teamID instead of dashboardId


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
}
```

**Edit**

To enter separate rows:

```
$memberId = $_POST['memberId'];
//$teamId = implode(',', $_POST['teamId']);
  $teamId = $_POST['teamId'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO teamMember (teamId, memberId) ";
$sql_concat="";
foreach ($teamId as $team) {
  if($sql_concat == "")
    $sql_concat .= " VALUES ('$team', '$memberId')";
  else
    $sql_concat .= " , ('$team', '$memberId')";
}
$sql .= $sql_concat;
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
}
```

Comment: SO now it must be work fine. Also check `$_POST['teamId']` is set or not because if none of check box is selected then you will get an error

Comment: It will insert a single row but not multiple, so for instance if i check say team1, team2, team3, it only inserts the last value of the series along with the members id but not all three with the members id

Comment: This assumes only one checkbox is selected - so the implode is redundant

Comment: @PhpDude you need to insert separate rows or single row with multiple values (with `,` delimiter )?

Comment: I need to insert seperate rows into a teamMembers table where there maybe lots of teamIds against the same memberIds

Comment: The page is failing now and no insert.

Comment: Ok its not failing anymore however nothing is inserted into the db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136664/discussion-between-b-desai-and-phpdude).

Comment: @PhpDude check now. Not execute query each time. instead of try this solution